# Powershell uploading files to SharePoint : Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s) error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to upload all .csv files from a C:/ to SharePoint.  The script runs  up to         $Ctx.ExecuteQuery() and returns this error.  I am able to run other PowerShell scripts on the site, and am the site owner, I suspect it is something other than access privileges.

Where do I start looking ?

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
+         $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

```
   Get-ChildItem "c:\users\xxx\downloads" -Filter *.csv | % {

        $eachFile =Get-ChildItem "c:\users\xxxx\downloads\" -Filter *.csv
        $eachFile | ForEach-Object{

       #parameters
            $SiteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/nrg"
            $LibraryName="Audit History"
            $UserName = "xxxx@x.onmicrosoft.com"
            $Password = "xx"
            $SecurePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

            #Setup the Context
            $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
            $Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
            $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials


        #Get the Library
        $Library =  $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)

        #Get the file from disk
        $FileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $OutputFile)).OpenRead()

        #Get File Name from source file path
        $SourceFileName = Split-path $eachFile -leaf

         #sharepoint online upload file powershell
        $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
        $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
        $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
        $FileCreationInfo.URL = $SourceFileName
        $FileUploaded = $Library.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)

        #powershell upload single file to sharepoint online
        $Ctx.Load($FileUploaded)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #Close file stream
        $FileStream.Close()

        write-host "File has been uploaded!"

        }
        }
```

Comment: Since you are looping over `$eachFile` with `ForEach-Object{..}`, you need to change `$SourceFileName = Split-path $eachFile -leaf` into `$SourceFileName = Split-path $_ -leaf`. Also, variable `$OutputFile` is never defined..

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to remove the Credentials to before  the ForEach-Object.